# Iterate through Files in Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: java, scala, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am attempting to implement a relatively simple ETL pipeline that iterates through files in a google cloud bucket. The bucket has two folders: /input and /output.

What I'm trying to do is write a Java/Scala script to iterate through files in /input, and have the transformation applied to those that are not present in /output or those that have a timestamp later than that in /output. I've been looking through the Java API doc for a function I can leverage (as opposed to just calling `gsutil ls ...`), but haven't had any luck so far. Any recommendations on where to look in the doc?
Edit: There is a better way to do this than using data transfer objects:

```
  public Page<Blob> listBlobs() {
    // [START listBlobs]
    Page<Blob> blobs = bucket.list();
    for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
      // do something with the blob
    }
    // [END listBlobs]
    return blobs;
  }
```

Old method:

```
  def getBucketFolderContents(
      bucketName: String
  ) = {
    val credential = getCredential
    val httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
    val requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential)
    val uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/" + URLEncoder.encode(
      bucketName,
      "UTF-8") +
      "o/raw%2f"
    val url = new GenericUrl(uri)
    val request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(uri)
    val response = request.execute()
    response

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list objects under a folder by setting the prefix string on the object listing API: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list
The results of listing are sorted, so you should be able to list both folders and then walk through both in order and generate the diff list.

Comment: Implemented the above solution using the doc @Mike provided and the java API example found here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/java-samples (I should point out I renamed "input" to "raw.")